# Lazy Loading with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a collection of a Cars object in my code.

My Domain Layer class contains the following:

```
    // Entity Framework backing field
    private ReadOnlyCollection<Car> _cars;

    public virtual ReadOnlyCollection<Car> Cars
    {
        get
        {
            AuditMethod(_cars);
            return _cars;
        }
        private set { _cars = value; }
    }
```

Note the property is marked as virtual to allow lazy loading.  In my Web Layer then I use this in a Web Api and if I want to return all the Cars from my a particular garage I can just do:

```
var cars = Garage.Cars;
```

Everything works as expected and they load in fine.  However due to the AuditMethod which runs when accessing the property like this it is performance is really decreasing when the numbers of Cars in a particular Garage gets high.  As I am just returning the data in this exposed Web API method and not worried about triggering the Audit information my idea was to write a method in the Domain layer which just returns the private field as below:

```
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Car> GetCarsForWebApi()
    {
        return _cars;
    }
```

Then in the Web API I attempted to do something like:

```
var cars = Garage.GetCarsForWebApi();
```

However when I break point this line I always get no data returning.  I am assuming it is because the Data is not lazy loaded in at this point.  Is there something I am missing to get this working?  I also dont want have a reference to my DAL Layer in my Domain Layer so would like to avoid a coded off the db.Context with a .Include to eagerly load the data if possible?

Comment: I have ran into this same problem when working with Web. I always just disable lazy loading and either use explicit or eager loading.

Comment: How bout moving AuditMethod(_cars) out of the Cars getter and using that? And to get cars with audits, create a new method GetCarsWithAuditMethod() with AuditMethod(_cars).

Comment: Is there a foreign key between cars and garage in database? And is your relation one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: @Alexander.  Yes the Cars table has a FK to GarageId.   And one garage contains many cars